# monacaからmBaaSの値を取得した値を並び替える方法

Tags: javascript, monaca

[ニフティクラウドmobile backend レベルアップセミナー　クーポン配信アプリを作ろう【Monaca編】の「お気に入り登録」](https://qiita.com/thuydg@github/items/caf3b3cb988bf76459ae#%E3%81%8A%E6%B0%97%E3%81%AB%E5%85%A5%E3%82%8A%E7%99%BB%E9%8C%B2%E6%A9%9F%E8%83%BD%E3%81%AE%E4%BD%9C%E6%88%90-1)で、Shop情報を以下のコードで取得しています。

```
//mBaaSにお気に入り登録されているShop情報を取得してリストに表示する
function showFavorite() {

  //リストをリセットします。
  $("#listFavoriteShop").empty();

  //表示名を指定します。
  $("#favorite_nickName").text(currentLoginUser.nickname + "のお気に入りショップ");

  //お気に入り登録した値を取得
  var fav_shops = currentLoginUser.favorite;

  //ショップ一覧を表示
  for (var i = 0; i < shopArray.length; i++) {
    var shop = shopArray[i];
    var selectStr = "selected='true'";

    //ショップのお気に入りが登録された場合の表示
    var tmpStrOff = "<div class='ui-field-contain'><label for='" + shop.objectId + "'>" + shop.name + "</label><select name='favorite_shop' id='" + shop.objectId + "' data-role='slider' data-theme='e' ><option value='off' " + selectStr+ ">Off</option><option value='" + shop.objectId + "'>On</option></select></div>";

    // //ショップのお気に入りが登録されていない場合の表示
    var tmpStrOn = "<div class='ui-field-contain'><label for='" + shop.objectId + "'>" + shop.name + "</label><select name='favorite_shop' id='" + shop.objectId + "' data-role='slider' data-theme='e' ><option value='off'>Off</option><option value='" + shop.objectId + "' " + selectStr+ " >On</option></select></div>";

    if ($.inArray(shop.objectId, fav_shops) == -1 ){
      $("#listFavoriteShop").append(tmpStrOff);
    }else{
      $("#listFavoriteShop").append(tmpStrOn);
    }
  }

  //Switchスライダーを更新
  $( "select[name=favorite_shop]" ).slider({
    defaults: true
  });
  $('select[name=favorite_shop]').slider('refresh');

  //画面遷移
  $.mobile.changePage('#FavoritePage');
}
```

```
このコードのままだと、nameの並び順を指定していないため、毎回、並び順が異なってしまいます。
ついては、ショップの名前順で昇順に表示したいのですが、どのように記述すればよろしいしょうか。

データストアの表示画面
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

並び替えるコードとしてorderで指定することは公式ドキュメントに記載がありますが、どのように指定すればいいのかわからず、質問させていただきました。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/135484

Answer (score 0):

> ついては、ショップの名前順で昇順に表示したいのですが、どのように記述すればよろしいしょうか。

### データストアの機能を利用する場合

Monacaのデータストアは、`order`メソッドでソートできるようです。

[app.js:211行目](https://github.com/ncmbadmin/MonacaAdvancePush/blob/full_version/www/js/app.js#L211)を以下に変更すればソートできると思います。

```
ShopClass.order("name").fetchAll()
```

### JavaScriptの標準機能を使う場合

オブジェクト配列は以下のようにソートできます。([参考: Array.prototype.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort))

```
shopArray = [{name: 'shopC'}, {name: 'shopB'}, {name: 'shopA'}];
var sortedShopArray =  shopArray.sort(function(a, b){
    if (a.name > b.name) {
        return 1;
    } else if (a.name === b.name) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return -1;
    }
})

console.log(sorttedShopArray);  // => [ { name: 'shopA' }, { name: 'shopB' }, { name: 'shopC' } ]
```

そのため、以下のように先にショップ一覧をソートしてから処理すれば良いと思います。

```
// ショップ一覧をソート
var sortedShopArray =  shopArray.sort(function(a, b){
  if (a.name > b.name) {
    return 1;
  } else if (a.name === b.name) {
    return 0;
  } else {
    return -1;
  }
});
// ショップ一覧を表示
for (var i = 0; i < sortedShopArray.length; i++) {
  var shop = sortedShopArray[i];
  // 以下、略
}
```